# Add charachters to the dates in a text with a lot of information

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a textfile with dates, names and adresses like so: 
190524 David Bakerstreet 190515 Peter Hollandstreet etc

I want to preceed the dates with  {" exactly and proceed the dates with ": exactly to make it fit a Dictionary. I tried the following, but it subs every date in file.txt for the latest in the loop, instead of changing one a a time, so every date i file.txt becomes the same. How can I do it?

```
file = open(file.txt)
FILE = file.read()
a = re.compile(r"\d\d\d\d\d\d") # To find dates like 190213
b = re.findall(a, FILE)         # Finding all the dates and put them in a list

for k in b:
    for q in FILE.split():
        if k in q:
            c = a.sub("{\""+k+"\":", FILE)
print(c)
```

Outcome: {"190515:" David Bakerstreet {"190515": Peter Hollandstreet etc

Outcome I want: {"190524:" David Bakerstreet {"190515": Peter Hollandstreet etc

Comment: How does your input file looks like?

Comment: Do you want many dictionaries and for each just a single key (date) and value (name+street)? Or one dictionary with many keys and values? Because your open curvy bracket without closing the previous one doesn't make sense.

Comment: its a nested Dictionary, the dates are the inner one, they will become the keys to the rest of the info, which will be values in a tuple, I close it with curvy brackets at the end.

Comment: You're not making a dictionary, you're making a string.

Comment: It wil be a dictionary when I am done with all the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `\1` token in the replacement to refer to a part of the string matched.

First, capture the 6 digits matched with a group. Use this regex:

```
(\d{6})
```

For the replacement string, instead of `"{\"" + k + "\":"`, you can simply use `"{\"\\1\":"`.

You don't actually need that many for loops either. Assuming the input file is small, I don't think you need any for loop.

```
a = re.compile(r"(\d{6})")
c = a.sub("{\"\\1\":", FILE)
print(c)
```

If your input file is large, then you might need to read it bit by bit, instead of the whole thing at once.

Comment: What does the \\1 mean in the sub(("{\"\\1\":") ?

Comment: @PasPro “whatever is matched in group 1”. If you look at the regex I used, group 1 is what’s inside the brackets.